# Passport google authentication with javascript fullstack

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, passport.js

I'm trying to add google authentication with passport in my application, that has been generated using yeoman fullstack-generator.

Inside my login controller i have this request:

```javascript
$scope.googleAuth = function(){
  $http.get('/auth/google');
};
```

but when i call this function i have this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=h…d=<my-client-ID-here>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I tried to fix that problem adding a middleware layer in my express.js file:

```javascript
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9000');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

but it still not working.
Is this the right solution? and is it safe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed the problem using an hyperlink instead of a button as following

```
<a target="_self" href="/auth/google" class="btn btn-danger">Google+</a>
```

I used `target="_self"`otherwise angular redirects to home page because, I think, it considers `/auth/google` as a route of my app.

Comment: How are you passing the result of the auth (i.e. the user object) back to your controller?

Comment: +1 Life Saver..Spend more than 3hrs on this one. :) Thanks a ton.